# Displaying a series of images upon scrolling in HTML/JS

Tags: javascript, html

I want to have a scroll unfold using a series of images and I am not sure what's wrong but when I mouse over nothing happens. Here is my code:

```
<html>
<body>

<img onmouseover="scroll(1)(this)" onmouseout="noScroll(this)" border="0" src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/ADI54pjibHuKYxVSWv5c1zKqT1jrJLkGJKkNdGmeg9QGQSn8qmevZmVKxYbHLkBglb9JCSEXMk6KuKD-ym2szJLlp3_HN8RGEM1ShXdfT8U0zQCyU7_18UEZdLfySIUhGnZ83lGhEheMvZcf6KCfAKKLKdGyReBlq-xlxMKhpvtLWVg9Y97_0zkjJ56H6n3_S8GiYDEs2PC_eikNDfHWU9b7n8QLJQ60lv1KNKI8XePgqY0ezhJI2TBAPAliyAH0GsDm6POmEJ2BntdnlhP5LDIZf1Mw9GRrcfCsiYMUJFa23i_uECe4weWo1GcvWltdaKiQtibC8r_-zxJmACJngR854oQIntCSrRZW_FKMRXGQTb2UUWKe9fGz090n3O6qQHAI5TBiPLK3PYPTtSIgxf-ItuwNNGjdKraNiYUGz3r7Hfx3qaJpnG6sLufL52MRCcfQD30X4NDtjny-9uHDXma6BEgwFR-RCtB-qrZJW8xKwZoGDK9mRw6QrYKpHSArZ-wHNbCrJISldQrQM_bFmyQP2xsUTNCYmlcBoHKmAo`HnkVTOLvm4eEJ6_rgDHG8cewbBChCCKh0z28DJvECF6iejEOEu1w7p4Ax0WeE4Q0PBqmo1bemD1DlHNRFXW1c_TLwUponyvDKI3I_VzA`o1Wqq_Tmw2eQ5BEoy-SYEz3XeGOq6g-YTkRw=s969-no" alt="Scroll" width="200" height="200">;



<script>
    function bigImg(x) {
      setTimeout(scroll(1), 10);
      setTimeout(scroll(2), 100);
      setTimeout(scroll(3), 200);
      setTimeout(scroll(4), 300);
      setTimeout(scroll(5), 400);
    }
    function scroll(1)(x){
      <img src="scroll(1).png" alt="scroll(1)">;
    }
    function scroll(2)(x){
      <img src="scroll(2).png">;
    }
    function scroll(3)(x){
      <img src="scroll(3)">;
    }
    function scroll(4)(x){
      <img src="scroll(4).png">;
    }
    function scroll(5)(x){
      <img src="scroll(5).png">;
    }
    function noScroll(x) {
      x.style.height = "200px";
      x.style.width = "200px";
    }
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Any input about syntax structure or the like would be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

This is horizontal scrolling of an image list. Hope this will help you.

CSS:-

```
.img-container {
    height: 180px;
    width: 100%;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow-x: scroll;
    overflow-y: hidden;
}
.item {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 8px 8px;
    border-top-right-radius: 4px;
    width: 150px;
    height: 100px;
    vertical-align: bottom;
    background-position: top left;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

Html:-

```
 <div class="row-fluid">
      <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-10 ">
        <div class="img-container">
          <!-- START PANEL -->
          <div
            class="item"
            style="background-image: url('http://placehold.it/150x100')"
          ></div>
          <div
            class="item"
            style="background-image: url('http://placehold.it/150x100')"
          ></div>
          <div
            class="item"
            style="background-image: url('http://placehold.it/150x100')"
          ></div>  <div
          class="item"
          style="background-image: url('http://placehold.it/150x100')"
        ></div>
        <div
          class="item"
          style="background-image: url('http://placehold.it/150x100')"
        ></div>
        <div
          class="item"
          style="background-image: url('http://placehold.it/150x100')"
        ></div>  <div
        class="item"
        style="background-image: url('http://placehold.it/150x100')"
      ></div>
      <div
        class="item"
        style="background-image: url('http://placehold.it/150x100')"
      ></div>
      <div
        class="item"
        style="background-image: url('http://placehold.it/150x100')"
      ></div>  <div
      class="item"
      style="background-image: url('http://placehold.it/150x100')"
    ></div>
    <div
      class="item"
      style="background-image: url('http://placehold.it/150x100')"
    ></div>
    <div
      class="item"
      style="background-image: url('http://placehold.it/150x100')"
    ></div>  <div
    class="item"
    style="background-image: url('http://placehold.it/150x100')"
  ></div>
  <div
    class="item"
    style="background-image: url('http://placehold.it/150x100')"
  ></div>
  <div
    class="item"
    style="background-image: url('http://placehold.it/150x100')"
  ></div>  <div
  class="item"
  style="background-image: url('http://placehold.it/150x100')"
></div>
<div
  class="item"
  style="background-image: url('http://placehold.it/150x100')"
></div>
<div
  class="item"
  style="background-image: url('http://placehold.it/150x100')"
></div>


          <!-- END PANEL -->
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```